# Group data by email and summarize- symfony/php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I getting data from db and parsing to array/json - this what I getting (100 rows per result):

```
 array[1] = (
  "CustomerId" => 1,
  "CustomerEmail" =>iii@gmail.com,
  "CustomerName" =>name1,
  "date" => "10-10-16",
```

"total" =>3

```
),
array[2] = (
  "CustomerId" => 2,
  "CustomerEmail" =>iii@gmail.com,
  "CustomerName" =>name2,
  "date" => "9-10-16",
"total" =>2
)
array[3] = (
  "CustomerId" => 3,
  "CustomerEmail" =>anotherEmail@gmail.com,
  "CustomerName" =>name3,
  "date" => "18-10-16",
  "total" =>54
)
```

My question is how can I group by email (customers that have the same email) the customers and what is the efficient way that the result will be like below.

"sum"- array in each email object that include a summarise of some data (for instance - "total" , and also take the same other data of the row that have the **recent date**)

```
  $customers['iii@gmail.com'] =  array(
    'c1' => array('name' => 'name1', 'id' => '1' ,"date"=>"10-10-16","total"=3"),

    'c2' => array('name' => 'name2', 'id' => '2',"date"=>"09-10-16","total"=>2),

    'sum' => array('name' => '2', 'id' => '1',"date"=>"date"=>"10-10-16","total"=>5),
    );
  $customers['anotherEmail@gmail.com] =  array(
    'c3' => array('name' => 'name', 'id' => '12',"date"=>"date"=>"18-10-16","total"=>54),
    'sum' => array('name' => '1', 'id' => '12',"date"=>"date"=>"18-10-16","total"=>54),
    );
```

and then parse all to json.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a new array and inserting customers into it:

```
$customers = [];

foreach ($data as $customer) {
    if (!isset($customers[$customer['customerEmail']])) {
        $customers[$customer['customerEmail']] = [];
    }

    array_push($customers[$customer['customerEmail']], $customer);
}
```

Then you can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-map.php) to go over the new `$customers` array, add the `sum` fields or apply any other filters to every group of customers:

```
$result = array_map(
    // Runs for each element of $customers
    function ($customersGroup) {
        // create your sum object
        $sum = ...

        // Insert the `sum` into $customersGroup
        $customersGroup['sum'] = $sum;

        // Return the modified $customersGroup
        return $customersGroup;
    },
    $customers
);
```

I hope this clears it up a little.

Comment: Hi it is working well but I edited my question because i have issue with the "sum" array - can you help me with that? thx

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with ? You can use the `array_map` callback to perform whatever actions necessary on each group. The raw groups are passed by as an argument (`$customersGroup`), and you should return the end result for that group, which in your case is the initial `$customersGroup` with an additional `sum` entry. I updated my answer to make this a little bit more clear.